# Trying to code two counts from one column in the same table

Tags: mysql

This is my first time working with SQL - and I'm trying to figure out how to determine the total number of rides from an Uber data set for two time frames "morning rush hour" i.e. BETWEEN '06:30:00' AND '09:30:00' and also for "evening rush hour" BETWEEN '16:30:00' AND '19:30:00'.

I have 6 columns in the one table - record_id, Pickup_date, Pickup_time, lat, lon, & base ---  but only need to return the total count for both rush hours... what I have so far for the morning rush is:

SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total_AM_Rush_Hour_Pickups
FROM uber_data_sep2014 
GROUP BY Pickup_time 
HAVING Pickup_time BETWEEN '06:30:00' AND '09:30:00';

but it returns three rows with the same value... and I can't figure out how to add in the second part - please help!

Comment: Remove the group by. If you want count of all in that time frame you don't want to group them by a specific time.

Comment: I want to count all - but in two time frames - 6:30am-9:30am and 4:30pm-7:30pm

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using a CASE statement to create two different counters?

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN Pickup_time BETWEEN '06:30:00' AND '09:30:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS MorningCount,
SUM(CASE WHEN Pickup_time BETWEEN '16:30:00' AND '19:30:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EveningCount
FROM uber_data_sep2014
```

Comment: I haven't learned CASE statements but I can try this out and see

Comment: Unfortunately the output is showing the exact same total for both time frames - there's no way that can be possible..

Comment: I would need a closer look at what the data looks like in the Pickup_time column.  Perhaps there is something in the time conversion that makes it always return 'true'.  Knowing what the data looks like may also answer my curiosity as to why the original query is returning only three rows.

Comment: For Example - the first 20 records show up like this under the 24 hr format: Pickup_Time
0:01:00
1:01:00
2:01:00
3:01:00
4:01:00
5:01:00
6:01:00
7:01:00
8:01:00
9:01:00
10:01:00
11:01:00
12:01:00
13:01:00
14:01:00
15:01:00
16:01:00
17:01:00
18:01:00

Comment: This could be two things.  One thought is that this data is from a dimension table of a data warehouse.  The other thought is that there is another column in the table that has the number of pickups for each minute.  If this is true for either case, it makes sense that the original query would give the same answer for morning and evening rush hour.